# Fetch API Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm following this online tutorial on using Fetch to consume API data; I was able to get the application to Fetch data using the JSON URL provided  in the tutorial. However, I made some modifications to the code and attempted to fetch data from a different JSON file and got an error:

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from "react-dom";
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.jsx';
import Footer from '../components/Footer.jsx';
import './ClientInfo.css';


class ClientInfo extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state= {
            titles: []
        };
    }

    
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(results => {    
          return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
          let titles = data.results.map((til) => { 
            return(                                  
              <div key={til.results}>              
                <p>{til.title} </p>    
              </div>
            )
          })
          this.setState({titles: titles});        
          console.log("state", this.state.titles);
        })
      }

  
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="container">
                        <div className="clientContainer">
                      {this.state.titles}
                        </div> 
            </div> 
            <Footer /> 
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default ClientInfo
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
let titles = data.results.map((til) => {
```

Could I get some help as what am doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like `data.results` is `undefined`.... are you use it is not just supposed to be `data.map()`?

Comment: The response is an array, it does not a have a  results property. so you need to remove .results `let titles = data.map((til) => { `

Comment: I mean, just console.log before each statement and see what you get. Shouldn't be hard to debug

Comment: can you console.log(data) in the callback and see if it actually contains results as the array or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.results - not array. Array data.map

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue. In the tutorial, which pulls images from the API; it has the line set up like so: let pictures = data.results.map((pic) => { .          ...It works in the tutorial, ...would you know the reason why, the images are being stored within an array.  I just modified the line to pull text. Thanks again